# Apache : Restrict access to URI, not resource

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'd like to restrict access to some URIs, but they do not physically match a clearly identified resource.
I explain : if you ask http://domainname/admin, you do not strictly go to the admin dir, you go to a script, with some params; and this script can also be used in other contexts.

So, i'd like to make something like folder access restriction, but based on the URI asked for, not on the actuel resource (cause the /admin folder exists, of course :D).

How could i do that ?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

In .htaccess Add the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^admin - [F,L]
```

This will deny access to paths starting with admin.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<Location>`/`</Location>` tags in your httpd.conf (or whatever it's called this week), insert any access restrictions between the tags. For instance

```
<Location /admin>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost, admins-workstation.example.com
</Location>
```